# Ubuntu workspace switching shortcuts don't work

Tags: unity, 16.04, shortcut-keys, thinkpad, workspaces

#### Core problem:

The following keyboard shortcuts for switching workspaces (unity viewports) are not working.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> for switching workspace above
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> for moving window to workspace above

These are the configured window manager key bindings (`dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/`):

```
move-to-workspace-left=['<Shift><Control><Alt>Left']
switch-to-workspace-left=['<Control><Alt>Left']
begin-move=['<Alt>F7']
maximize-horizontally=['disabled']
switch-to-workspace-10=['disabled']
switch-to-workspace-11=['disabled']
switch-to-workspace-12=['disabled']
switch-to-workspace-1=['<Super>Home']
switch-to-workspace-2=['disabled']
panel-run-dialog=['<Alt>F2']
switch-to-workspace-3=['disabled']
switch-to-workspace-5=['disabled']
switch-to-workspace-6=['disabled']
switch-to-workspace-7=['disabled']
switch-to-workspace-8=['disabled']
show-desktop=['<Control><Super>d']
raise=['disabled']
maximize=['<Control><Super>Up']
switch-to-workspace-9=['disabled']
begin-resize=['<Alt>F8']
switch-to-workspace-4=['disabled']
toggle-above=@as []
panel-main-menu=['<Super>s']
unmaximize=['<Control><Super>Down']
switch-input-source=['Caps_Lock']
switch-to-workspace-right=['<Control><Alt>Right']
move-to-workspace-down=['<Shift><Control><Alt>Down']
move-to-workspace-1=['<Primary>Alt_L']
switch-to-workspace-down=['<Control><Alt>Down']
toggle-shaded=['<Control><Alt>s']
minimize=['<Control><Alt>KP_0']
switch-windows-backward=['disabled']
toggle-on-all-workspaces=@as []
lower=['disabled']
activate-window-menu=['<Alt>space']
maximize-vertically=['disabled']
move-to-workspace-up=['<Shift><Control><Alt>Up']
move-to-workspace-right=['<Shift><Control><Alt>Right']
toggle-maximized=['<Control><Alt>KP_5']
switch-input-source-backward=['<Alt>Shift_L']
close=['<Alt>F4']
switch-windows=['disabled']
switch-to-workspace-up=['<Control><Alt>Up']
```

#### System info

- Lenovo ThinkPad Edge e330
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#### `xev` output

- Internal keyboard: [redacted](//paste.ubuntu.com/22607494/), [full](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p09y9xk7jf77co6/xev%20%28downscreen%29.log?dl=0)
- External keyboard: [redacted](//paste.ubuntu.com/22607838/), [full](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ufbhj82aw2krod/xev%28outkeyboard%29.log?dl=0)
- Internal keyboard (when press ctrl+alt+down) [redacted](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22696675/), [full](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22696951/)

Comment: Это англоязычный сайт. Вопросы надо на английском задавать.

Comment: На русском можно тут http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php

Comment: Her workspace switching keyboard shortcuts aren't working. I'll fix the translation once i have time

Comment: Somebody please edit this question to include proper title. That google translate version is horrible

Comment: Инесса, рабочие места изначально не включены. Вы их включили или нет ?

Comment: thank you for comments! i understand about translate and edit the question

Comment: @Serg , изначально из коробки рабочие места включены не были. Для того, чтобы их добавить ставила Unity Twek Tool. 

Да, проблемы с клавиатурой наблюдались и до этого

Comment: @InessaPokromkina Ну вобще-то Unity Twek Tool для этого не нужен , но он позволяет менять спецефическое количество рабочих мест. ОК , это больше звучит как баг ,  и лутчее решение что можно предложить это попробывать срипт на питоне который будет переключать рабочие места. Но до этого, я хотел бы узнать кое что еще. Вы с терминалом (командной строкой ) как , знакомы или не очень ?

Comment: @InessaPokromkina К стати, если нужен перевод коментариев , дайте мне знать

Comment: Please execute the above commands from David and [edit] your question to include them.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, here is keybinding dump: [keybinding dump](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61xfmebmfnzzq43/keybindingdump.log?dl=0)


here is [xev with internal keyboard](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p09y9xk7jf77co6/xev%20%28downscreen%29.log?dl=0) 

and [xev with external keyboard] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ufbhj82aw2krod/xev%28outkeyboard%29.log?dl=0)

sorry, i didnt clean it well

Comment: As far as I can tell, you never pressed Ctrl, Alt, and ↑ at the same time on the internal keyboard. Are you sure you really hat them pressed down at the same time (they don't need to *go* down at the same time but they need to *be* down at the same time at some point for the key combination to be registered). On the external keyboard they were pressed at the same time but in the wrong order, I believe; you need to press the involved modifier keys (i. e. Ctrl, Alt, and optionally Shift) first, keep the pressed, then press the ↑ key for the key combination to be registered.

Comment: If the combined keys are in inconvenient locations for you (and have trouble pressing all keys at the same time or any other reason), you can change them in *Gnome Control Center* (`gnome-control-center`), section *Keyboards*, tab *Shortcuts*, subsection *Navigation*. I have all the workspace keyboard shortcuts based on the Super key (a.k.a. the Windows key), e. g. Super+↑ to switch to the above workspace.

Comment: By the way, which window manager do you use? Unity? Gnome Shell? You mention “Unity viewports” but the configuration path `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/` only affects Gnome Shell.